# "Sic on" or "Sick on"?

Tags: orthography, homophones

What is the actual spelling of "sic"/"sick" in a phrase like "I will sic my dog on you"? This is a tricky one to look up in an online dictionary, every match seems to be referring to an editor's mark for a mistake.

Comment: The word is given in the verb definition on this page: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sic It says "variants: or less commonly sick" so both spellings exist according to Merriam-Webster.

Comment: In the US I have *always* seen this as *sic*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems both spellings are used...

> **sick**<sup>2</sup>
>   (also sic)
>   VERB [WITH OBJECT]
>   sick something on
>   1 Set a dog on.
>   *‘the plan was to surprise the heck out of the grizzly by sicking the dog on him’*
>
> 1.1 sick someone on  *informal*
>   Set someone to pursue, keep watch on, or accompany (another)
>   *‘who sicked those two on to us?’*

[Oxford Dictinaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sick)

Comment: Personally I prefer the 'sic' spelling, only because 'sick' exists as a verb with a very different meaning. 'Sic' only exists as a loan word from Latin meaning 'as' or 'so' which means that using 'sic' as a verb is less confusing.